# To find interval of convergence of given power series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

If $f(x)$=$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} x^{n}$ where $c_{n+4}=c_{n}$ for all $n\geq 0$.What is the interval of convergence of series.Any hint.

Comment: What if the condition was $c_{n+1}=c_n$ instead? Can you do it then?

Comment: In this case it will be $-1<=x<1$..

Comment: Good answer. Now try $c_{n+2}=c_n$ instead. It is a bit harder. Can you find a way to use the previous case?

Comment: No.tried a lot  but what is troubling me is this lim$c_{n+1}/c_{n}$?

Comment: On the basis of logic given by @John Watson...is the answer to second case is (-1,1)...just don't want to leave the question unanswered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $$ \sum = a_0+a_1x+... = (a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3)(1+x^4+x^8+...) = p(x)\cdot {1\over 1-x^4}$$
where $|x^4|<1$ and $p(x)= a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$. So $x\in(-1,1)$.

Comment: So,can I say in all cases if $c_{n+k}=c_{n}$ is given and k is even,interval will be (-1,1)

Comment: What if it was given that $c_{n+3}=c_{n}$..I try and I think $x$ will take all values except 1 but interval cannot be of such form..so I am puzzled..please explain this part ..

Comment: Yes, because $|x^k|<1$ so $|x|<1$ so $x\in (-1,1)$ in any case.

Comment: and one little doubt why $|x|$ cannot be greater than 1.

Comment: Well that is something you will have to look at your school book.

Comment: Ok...then in the case where k is given odd, interval will be -1<=x<1..

Comment: Always, not only for $k$ odd.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you say..I was asking if k is given odd for e.g. $c_{n+3}$=$c_{n}$ then will the interval be -1<=x<1 always...sorry for troubling you too much..

Comment: If $c_{n+k}=c_n$ for each $n$ the solution is $x\in (-1,1)$ independent of $k$.